# Shell script error on filename with spaces

Tags: ssh, bash, shell, ubuntu-12.04, gzip

I have a bash script that search for every static file located under my server root and stores a gzipped version next to each file. I got it from http://wiki.linuxwall.info/doku.php/en:ressources:dossiers:nginx:nginx_performance_tuning

The problem is that it doesn't work with filenames with spaces, my sites don't use any right now, and I'll try it won't ever, but I'm not the only one working in the front-end so I might not be able to control it always, so I just want to make sure this script works for files that have spaces too. Hope someone can take a look and hep me fix it.

```
#! /bin/bash

FILETYPES=("*.html" "*.woff" "*.css" "*.jpg" "*.jpeg" "*.gif" "*.png" "*.js")
# specify a list of directories to check recursively
DIRECTORIES="/usr/share/nginx/www/"

for currentdir in $DIRECTORIES
do
   for i in "${FILETYPES[@]}"
   do
      find $currentdir -iname "$i" -exec bash -c 'PLAINFILE="{}";GZIPPEDFILE="{}".gz; \
         if [ -e "$GZIPPEDFILE" ]; \
         then   if [ `stat --printf=%Y $PLAINFILE` -gt `stat --printf=%Y $GZIPPEDFILE` ]; \
                then    echo "$GZIPPEDFILE outdated, regenerating"; \
                        gzip -9 -f -c $PLAINFILE > $GZIPPEDFILE; \
                 fi; \
         else echo "$GZIPPEDFILE is missing, creating it"; \
              gzip -9 -c $PLAINFILE > $GZIPPEDFILE; \
         fi' \;
  done
done
```

Comment: No need for `stat`: `if [[ $plainfile -nt $gzippedfile ]]`. In Bash you can use single square brackets, but double square brackets are [more powerful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/bash-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces/2188369#2188369). It is recommended that you use lower case variable names by habit to avoid the possibility of name collision with shell variables. Instead of a long `-exec` clause with `find`, use `-print0` and pipe it to a Bash `while read -r -d '' varname` loop. Quoting will be simplified and you won't be running your `bash -c` script repeatedly

Comment: for each file. Instead of using `for` loops for the directories use multiple arguments to `find`: `find $directories -iname ...` which works as long as there aren't spaces in the directory names.

Comment: Thanks @DennisWilliamson I am an absolute beginner in bash or shell scripts, after reading your link to your other post I have changed the stat part for the `if [[ $plainfile -nt $gzippedfile ]]`, however I have no idea how to make the other changes you suggested, as I'm not familiar with it. Thanks for your help

Comment: completely remove `for currentdir in $DIRECTORIES` and its associated `done` and change the variable from `$currentdir` to `$directories` (remembering to change the case elsewhere following my advice to use lower case variable names). Instead of doing `-exec bash -c '...'` use `-print0 | while read -r -d '' plainfile; do gzippedfile=$plainfile.gz; if ...` followed by the rest of the script (don't forget to remove the single quote and `\;` on the last line. On all the other lines, you can remove the final semicolon and backslash. See this [paste bin](http://pastebin.com/Xbwxxvs6)

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thanks, I tried your suggestion but now it doesn't do anything, I run the script and it doesn't even takes take, the console is ready again as soon as I hit enter. I copied it exactly as your pastebin

Comment: I made a couple of errors. Change the variables on lines 7 and 9: `for i in "${filetypes[@]}"` and `find $directory`

Comment: Thank you @DennisWilliamson , did what you said, and had to change $directory for $directories as it is how it was declared, and it worked, now it takes just a fraction of a second as opposed to before when it would take several seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the variables with filenames in them so they aren't interpreted as multiple arguments to a command:

```
#! /bin/bash

FILETYPES=("*.html" "*.woff" "*.css" "*.jpg" "*.jpeg" "*.gif" "*.png" "*.js")
# specify a list of directories to check recursively
DIRECTORIES="/usr/share/nginx/www/"

for currentdir in $DIRECTORIES
do
   for i in "${FILETYPES[@]}"
   do
      find "$currentdir" -iname "$i" -exec bash -c 'PLAINFILE="{}";GZIPPEDFILE="{}".gz; \
         if [ -e "$GZIPPEDFILE" ]; \
         then   if [ `stat --printf=%Y "$PLAINFILE"` -gt `stat --printf=%Y "$GZIPPEDFILE"` ]; \
                then    echo "$GZIPPEDFILE outdated, regenerating"; \
                        gzip -9 -f -c "$PLAINFILE" > "$GZIPPEDFILE"; \
                 fi; \
         else echo "$GZIPPEDFILE is missing, creating it"; \
              gzip -9 -c "$PLAINFILE" > "$GZIPPEDFILE"; \
         fi' \;
  done
done
```